# What should I study real analysis or calculus?

Tags: soft-question, self-learning, book-recommendation

So I can do elementary single variable calculus (except series), also I am familiar with $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ definition of the limit, and also read the definition of  Darboux integral, but don't remember it fully. I want to self-study more by myself. And I don't know whether I should choose some not so rigorous calculus book (which maybe includes some multivariable calculus) but which will teach to do examples or some rigorous real analysis book. So what would you suggest me to choose and what book would you suggest?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems like an opinion-based question. Also your requirement is not sufficient in your statement.

Comment: This is much of a personal favor, but I would recommend you learning some multivariable calculus first. There are two reasons. 1. You cannot do mathematics without a strong computation abillity (unless you are Grothendieck). 2. Some part of real analysis would make more sense if you are familiar with multivariable calculus.

Comment: I love Abbot's "understanding analysis"

Answer (score 1):

I am italian, and the usual program in our university starts more or less directly with Mathematical Analysis. However, in high school we learn basic (really basic) calculus rules.

According to your description, I would suggest to review your knowledge of calculus, and to get acquainted with advanced calculus (functions of several real variables). You should move on to Mathematical Analysis once you know *by heart* all the besic definitions of calculus (limits, continuity, derivative, integral).

I like Serge Lang's books (published by Springer-Verlag), but the celebrated books by Tom Apostol (three volumes on calculus) could be a good choice. If you feel ready to learn some *hard* mathematical analysis, with rigorous proofs of everything, you can read Walter Rudin's *Principles of mathematical analysis*.